# Fake utcnow for the pytest

Tags: python, datetime, unit-testing, mocks

I want to create a pytest with a fake `utcnow`, but also I need to preserve the functionality of all other `datetime` methods. Simple example here:

```
import datetime as dt


class FakeTime(dt.datetime):
    fake_time = None

    @classmethod
    def utcnow(cls):
        return cls.fake_time


def str_2_time(str_dt: str) -> dt.datetime:
    """Shortcut to do convert the string to datetime"""
    return dt.datetime.strptime(str_dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')


def test_patch_datetime():
    for utc_time in ['2019-01-01 10:00', '2019-02-01 13:00', '2019-03-01 16:00']:
        FakeTime.fake_time = str_2_time(utc_time)
        dt.datetime = FakeTime
        assert dt.datetime.utcnow() == str_2_time(utc_time)
```

Is this the right way?

The method `str_2_time` just need to show that all other methods of the datetime works fine.

Comment: I highly recommend this lib for mocking `now` in python tests https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Comment: @Anentropic thank you, but if i will need more options i will add the package to the project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482067/1562285), subclassing `datetime.datetime` seems the way to go.

There is no use for the `str_2_time` method though. You can easily inline this, or even simpler, just use the `datetime.datetime` constructor:

```
def test_patch_datetime():
    for utc_time in [
        dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10),
        dt.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 13),
        dt.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 16),
    ]:
        FakeTime.fake_time = utc_time
        dt.datetime = FakeTime
        assert dt.datetime.utcnow() == utc_time
```

You should be aware that this can have side effects in other parts of your code, so it might be needed to replace it back with the original class after  the test method:

```
def test_patch_datetime():
    datetime_orig = dt.datetime

    utc_times = [
        dt.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 10),
        dt.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 13),
        dt.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 16),
    ]
    for utc_time in utc_times:
        FakeTime.fake_time = utc_time
        dt.datetime = FakeTime
        assert dt.datetime.utcnow() == utc_time
    dt.datetime = datetime_orig
    # print(dt.datetime.utcnow())
    assert dt.datetime.utcnow() > max(utc_times)
```

Comment: thank you, but the method `str_2_time` just need to show that all other methods of the `datetime` works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I do:

1. Separate module, for example `utils.py`, that contains:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_utcnow() -> datetime:
    return datetime.utcnow()
```

2. Use this function everywhere in my code.
3. Add the mocking fixture in `tests/conftest.py`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pytest

from .. import utils

@pytest.fixture
def mock_utcnow(monkeypatch):
    now = datetime.min

    def wrapped(delta=0.0):
        when = now + timedelta(delta)
        monkeypatch.setattr(utils, "get_utcnow", lambda: when)
        return when

    return wrapped
```

4. Now it's easy to use it in your tests:

```
def test(mock_utcnow):
    now = mock_utcnow()
    new_now = mock_utcnow(0.1)
```

Additionally, with this fixture you can set the returning value with desired offset.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i don't understand how it should help for my case.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want `utcnow` to return fake datetime.
So, using code from my answer:
1. You will use `utils.get_utcnow` in your real code, not in the tests.
2. In the tests you'll use fixture, that mocks `utils.get_utcnow`. After you call mocking function, every call of `utils.get_utcnow` in your real code will return fake datetime.

Comment: But with the code from my answer you'll get `datetime.min` by default, and after you can increase its value by adding `timedelta`, e.g. by calling `mock_utcnow(0.1)`.

Comment: If you want to start not with a `datetime.min`, you can extend fixture [with this](https://gist.github.com/szobov/f670259ee6b0de7db1cf86ad65c678ca)

But it requires more code in your tests.